# how to reference a specific function where two functions in scope have the same name

Tags: scala

Given that we have two functions in scope with the same name but a different parameter list. How can I distinguish one from the other, such as in the case of trying to access the `tupled` function

Example:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)


def f(s: String, l: Long): String = ???
def f(i: Int, l: Long): String = ???

val t:((String, Long)) => String = f.tupled

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:15: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method f of type (i: Int, l: Long)String
and  method f of type (s: String, l: Long)String
match expected type ?
val t:((String, Long)) => String = f.tupled
```

Simplifying the problem to function literals yields:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def f(i: Int, l: Long): String = ???
def f(s: String, l: Long): String = ???

val g = f _

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:15: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method f of type (s: String, l: Long)String
and  method f of type (i: Int, l: Long)String
match expected type ?
val g = f _
        ^
```

But the explicit type annotation in the function literal example manages to solve the problem, where as for the `apply` method above in the context of `tupled` did not work

```
scala>

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def f(s: String, l: Long): String = ???
def f(i: Int, l: Long): String = ???

val g: (String, Long) => String  = f _

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

f: (s: String, l: Long)String <and> (i: Int, l: Long)String
f: (s: String, l: Long)String <and> (i: Int, l: Long)String
g: (String, Long) => String = $$Lambda$1458/794413935@60cbba57
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way you can achieve this

```
val t1 = (f(_: String, _: Long)).tupled
val t2 = (f(_: Int, _: Long)).tupled
```

output

```
t1: ((String, Long)) => String = scala.Function2$$Lambda$1188/922196321@3994b698
t2: ((Int, Long)) => String = scala.Function2$$Lambda$1188/922196321@4249db51
```

Comment: Actually did end up consolidating my last two lines in my answer to come up with what you have done here. Comes out to quite cryptic syntax...

Answer (score 0):

I found the following hack for the `tupled` problem:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def f(s: String, l: Long): String = ???
def f(i: Int, l: Long): String = ???

val g: (String, Long) => String  = f _
val t = g.tupled

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

f: (s: String, l: Long)String <and> (i: Int, l: Long)String
f: (s: String, l: Long)String <and> (i: Int, l: Long)String
g: (String, Long) => String = $$Lambda$1476/1981627424@172f2717
t: ((String, Long)) => String = scala.Function2$$Lambda$259/530042637@bda4cbe
```